# Writing formatted text to a file iphone

Tags: ios, formatting

I am looking to export data that a user creates in my app in a formatted style. What I mean by this is I would like it to have capabilities like a word document with centered headers, larger font in certain places, etc... In the end the user will be emailing the document, which is why I would like it to look nicer than a standard plain text document. There has to be a way to do this right?

If you could point me in the right direction to get this functionality that would help me a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an HTML document with inline styling.  You can then use that directly in the body of the email message as an HTML email (I know they can sometimes be frowned upon).

But to be honest, that'll be the quickest way to achieve what you are after.

Comment: I was thinking HTML might be the way to go... is it possible to do the same thing but within a document so it can be saved rather than just in the email body?

Comment: Yes, just create the HTML in an NSString and use `- [NSString writeToFile:atomically:encoding]`

Comment: But doesn't simply writing HTML to a string and writing that to a file actually write out the HTML without it being translated when the file is opened?

Comment: Open it in a UIWebView if you want to view it still within the app.  In an email set as an HTML email, it will format as HTML.  If added as an attachment to an email with the extension .html it will open in a desktop web browser.  Total win-win and compatibility if you ask me.

Comment: Very nice... Looks like the easiest route at least... I think Ill set it as the body of the email as well as attaching it, so they can choose what they want to do with it. This seems good for now, but if I feel up to it maybe creating a pdf (hard to do I guess) will be my next option

Comment: Question... I got the html working great (thanks) but now im wonder if there is a good way to do the following... My html code basically creates a formatted page, but I would like to fill in the data with the data my app received from the user... How would I place the right text in the html string to do this?

Answer (score 0):

maybe can you give a look at:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/parts/dtrichtexteditor/
https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView
https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad/Examples/TextEditor/

and this apple documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/RTFAndAttrStrings.html

Comment: From my understanding this would be a very heavyweight solution to format some existing information, rather than needing an editor.